# Android SDK: How to Generate and Export excel file containing ArrayList data

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app where the user generates data that populates an ArrayList. My goal is to generate an excel sheet where this data is simply inputted into a single column (A1, A2,...) and exported on to some external storage.

I've researched various methods of generating excel sheets(specifically Java for Excel), but there's such a wide variety of external libraries to choose from and I'm not quite sure which is the most efficient and relevant to use.

Any direction as to which external libraries are best to use/guidance on generating an excel sheet using ArrayList data would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "...Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it..." "I've researched various methods of generating excel sheets(specifically Java for Excel), but there's such a wide variety of external libraries to choose from and I'm not quite sure which is the most efficient and relevant to use" Of course the answers are going to be opinionated, but its for the sake of determining what library would be most efficient and advice on such. Bit discouraging to ask a question about coding efficiency on a coding forum to have it met with a litany of off-topic designations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although There are a lot of options to do so I would suggest the following, **Please choose one of them based on your requirement.**

**1) Apache [POI](https://poi.apache.org/download.html)

2) Google sheets [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/)**

**Apache POI** is free open sourced  in active development and has good community support. I have personally used it and I was very satisfied with the result, You have very good control over how the data can be represented. BUT the limitation here is that it will be saved locally, however you can upload it to a server and share it with others. Also there is no limit on the API usage.

On the other hand **Google Sheets API** does the same thing and can support multiple people writing into the same cell BUT there is an overhead of adding a sign-in(quite simple) as the data is saved in your google account. And there is a [limit](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) on the number of operation

If the requirement is just offline then go with Apache POI, If it is more than that choose the second one. There are a lot of examples and tutorials for both of them.

Comment: Okay, my application only needs to generate an excel file for the user locally and have it saved to some external storage on the device, so I think the Apache would best suit my needs. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache POI api to generate these type of excel reports. 
Apache POI is very power